# import {BrowserRouter, Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'; brought 15 errors

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-router-dom/dist/index.js 13:0-836
export 'AbortedDeferredError' (reexported as 'AbortedDeferredError') was not found in 'react-router' (possible exports: Await, MemoryRouter, Navigate, Outlet, Route, Router, RouterProvider, Routes, UNSAFE_DataRouterContext, UNSAFE_DataRouterStateContext, UNSAFE_DataStaticRouterContext, UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext, UNSAFE_enhanceManualRouteObjects, createMemoryRouter, createRoutesFromChildren, createRoutesFromElements, renderMatches, useActionData, useAsyncError, useAsyncValue, useHref, useInRouterContext, useLoaderData, useLocation, useMatch, useMatches, useNavigate, useNavigation, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext, useParams, useResolvedPath, useRevalidator, useRouteError, useRouteLoaderData, useRoutes)

Comment: To avoid getting blacklisted, use this guide to ask better questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you installed incompatible versions of `react-router` and `react-router-dom` individually? You only need the latter if that is what you are using.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could also share your source code so that we can better understand your problem and provide a more accurate solution. Without the source code, it's difficult to diagnose the issue and provide a specific solution. Additionally, sharing your code allows other users to learn from your problem and potentially use the solution in the future. Please consider sharing your code in the future to help facilitate a more efficient and effective troubleshooting process.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed this while your React app was running, stop it and restart. This fixed the same problem for me. Apparently it's supposed to detect new installs, but it didn't for me.

Answer (score 1):

Do this.

```
Import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";
Import React from 'react';
```

Also make sure that you have installed the following packages;

```
react-dom, react-router, react-router-dom.
```

Comment: Thank you. I've installed the three packages but it kept showing me these errors:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HXsD-uWgQI1wxTnDkooUvKGpHZXLeRIn/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are installing `react-dom, react-router, and react-router-dom` in the right directory